# Django Toolbar gives different times when same template is loaded

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

When using the Django debug toolbar, it says a page might load in say 4000 ms. But when we reload the page (with ctrl+F5 to clear the cache) it says it loads in say 4400 ms -- or 3600 ms. Is there a more accurate way to benchmark the load time? The reason is that we want to optimize page load times and want to make sure that we can see cause and effect clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be some variation in the amount of time it takes a program to do anything--on a typical computer there are tens to hundreds of processes simultaneously competing for resources, so the exact load time will vary depending on how much else is going on at that exact moment.

The best way to benchmark is not to look at the time take by a single page load, but rather the average time over a bunch of loads.  There are many tools to help you do that--[Apache jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is one.

You may also want to look into profiling your app rather than just measuring the overall load time--that will help you identify which bits of your code are called most frequently and contribute the most to the total time taken.  Guess-and-check optimizations are likely to be much more time consuming.  See the [Django docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango) or Google "profiling django" many more resources.

Comment: Super! We figured it was the compute time. It's helpful to know though that there are more efficient ways than guess-and-check so we will definitely check out these resources. Thank you!